# Website wider than body?

Tags: html, css, drupal, responsive-design

I have this [site](http://aldagenais.pearcreative.ca/one-page) someone is  building for me and we're having issues figuring out why the page is wider horizontally than the body. It's suppose to be a responsive site based on this [template](http://preview.okler.net/porto/2.6.0/index-one-page.html).

[image]

If I inspect the html or body, they aren't as large as the page is rendering so I'm not sure what's causing this.

Comment: Please include some code for us to inspect. You might not have `overflow: hidden;` or you might have a div with a fixed width somewhere, or a floated div hanging out to the right of the whole template. It's hard for us to tell without some code to check.

Comment: dward's answer below should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your stylesheet, you have an explicit `width` set for your `h2`, as seen in your `theme-elements.css:25`.

If you remove that `width: 1170px` attribute, the site seems to work fine when your site is at it's widest breakpoint. You might go back and look through your stylesheet to see what other explicit width's you've set to other natural and normal block level elements. Going back through your CSS will also help you fix any width issues you have at other breakpoints.

Comment: I've disabled that width but from what I can see all it did was move the h2 header to the left and the page still remains the same size. http://imgur.com/NY57kkn

Comment: Notice now that you don't have a horizontal scrollbar. If you re-enable that width for `<h2>`, you'll see that it breaks in the footer columns you've made. To combat the issue with "same size," well, that'll take some more explanation from you. Same size as what? You'll need to describe that more clearly.

Comment: I do have a horizontal scroll bar though, I mean the scrollbar hasn't changed when i disabled the width. It's the same size and the page can be scrolled to the right beyond the body. I highlighted the room in the scrollbar in yellow.

Comment: You have several issues with width throughout your CSS file. Your ART NOW section isn't wrapped in the same elements. Your section Get Involved and it's next container `.content` has issues. To be honest, without being rude, you have several issues with explicit widths being set either by CSS or JS, or both.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issues, I'll try to look through the CSS and find those explicit widths

Comment: @Batman if dward's answer(s) is acceptable, it would be helpful to him and the community if you accepted it :-)

Comment: @TylerH I will when I've fixed the issue. I've tried disabling the width and that didn't work, there's mentioned other issues so I'll have to look into them and try things out.

Comment: To help aid your frustration @Batman, my best guess without too much further inspection is that some of your JS files/plugins are causing some of the headaches. I can see inline styles on a slider of some sort, which most likely means it's coming from some JS file applying dynamic properties. I'd try removing elements/sections on the page (just commenting them out even would work) to help troubleshoot. Time consuming yes, but worth the time.

Comment: It's actually the container above `.content`. [Here's a pic](http://i.imgur.com/3VPDSii.png) showing the issue when resizing the browser to mobile (quick and dirty test). The `ul` that is the panels or slider content in this case, has explicit width's set from some JS file I'm guessing. As I mentioned, you'll need to go through your site with a fine tooth comb, at all your breakpoints, and keep removing elements until you find and fix the issue. Then add in one section again and rinse and repeat.